# How to connect ASP.NET Web API for SQL Server database on Somee.com?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core, connection-string

A string of this type is issued by the site SOMEE to connect to SQL Server:

```
workstation id=xxx.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=xxxx;pwd=xxxx;data source=xxxx.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=xxxx;
```

On a local database, I use the following connection string:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ugOJ.png)

I published the project and uploaded it to somee.com, I can't establish a connection to a remote database. How to convert `SOMEE-DB-CONNECTION-STRING` to a normal Entity Framework Core 7 connection string as on a local one?

Tried some ways, couldn't find a solution.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To connect your ASP.NET Web API to a SQL Server database on Somee.com using Entity Framework Core, you can modify your connection string as follows:

1. Replace the connection string in your `appsettings.json` or `appsettings.Development.json` file with the one you provided by Somee.com:

```json
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection": "workstation id=xxx.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=xxxx;pwd=xxxx;data source=xxxx.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=xxxx;"
}
```

2. In your `Startup.cs` file, in the `ConfigureServices` method, configure your DbContext to use this connection string:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});
```

Make sure to replace `YourDbContext` with the actual name of your DbContext.

3. Now, you can use Entity Framework Core as you normally would with a local database, and it will connect to the remote SQL Server database provided by Somee.com using the connection string you specified in `appsettings.json`.

Remember to replace the placeholders (xxx, xxxx) in the connection string with your actual database credentials. Also, ensure that your remote SQL Server instance on Somee.com allows external connections and that the firewall rules are properly configured to allow your web application to connect to it.

Comment: Looks like ChatGPT?

Comment: @DaleK Yup. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77024508/4832499) as well. I'm surprised that deletion had no repercussions.